# Javascript variable loses its value

Tags: javascript, dropzone.js, dropzone

**Background:** I use *butSubmit* to submit the form which has the Dropzone and some other fields - the dropzone is processed first, and if everything goes right than the fields are processed too

**Problem:**  The files (from dropzone) are uploaded correctly, and `error3` gets the *DropzoneOK* value. However, when I access the value on button click, it is shown empty.
I tried with `var error3=""` outside the function too (that means, on line 4).

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;

    var myDropzone = new Dropzone('#myDropzone', {       
      autoProcessQueue: false,
      uploadMultiple: true,
      parallelUploads: 20,
      maxFiles: 20,
      addRemoveLinks: true,
      init: function() {
        this.on("errormultiple", function(){
          error3="DropzoneErr";
        });
        this.on("queuecomplete", function () {
          this.removeAllFiles();
        });
        this.on("successmultiple", function(file, response) {
          error3="DropzoneOK";   //It works
        });
      }
    });

    $('#butSubmit').click(function () {
       var error3="";
       myDropzone.processQueue();
       console.log(error3);  //error3 is shown to be empty
       if(error3!="DropzoneOK")
            error3 = "<p style='color:red'>Please try again</p>";
    });

  });
</script>
```

Comment: Move var error3 to line 4.

Comment: @SreeramPadmanabhan As I said, I tried this before the current version posted and didn't work. At your suggestion, I tried again, but the result is the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're declaring this variable again with an empty value.

```
$('#butSubmit').click(function () {
       var error3=""; <--- wrong, remove this
       myDropzone.processQueue();
       console.log(error3);  //error3 is shown to be empty
       if(error3!="DropzoneOK")
            error3 = "<p style='color:red'>Please try again</p>";
    });
```

Once you've removed that line add `var error3=""` as the very first line like so:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var error3="";
    Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;

    var myDropzone = new Dropzone('#myDropzone', {       
      autoProcessQueue: false,
...
```

Comment: As I said, I tried this before the current version posted and didn't work. At your suggestion, I tried again, but the result is the same.

Comment: Did you remove the line I mentioned at the same time? If yes, this is likely an issue with async operations and you'll probably find that it's because the processQueue() operations has not completed yet.

Comment: And how can I solve the problem? (I removed that line)

Comment: You've already got a callback for success: `this.on("successmultiple"...`. Try putting your logic in there.